how to solve conflit between to filament 3 laravel package and valex admin template in some colors variable?
I installed valex laravel template (based on tailwindcss) and it worked really well but when I add filament 3 package, I have this problem.
Some css classs used by filamanet like text-danger-600 not showing the right color.
Maybe because there are conflicts in valex custom colors and filament custom colors in  ./vendor/filament/support/tailwind.config.preset.
There are conflicts between color variable in tailwind.config.preset.je  of filament and color variable valex in tailwind.config.je
please help
thanks
look at the  tailwond.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
import preset from './vendor/filament/support/tailwind.config.preset'


const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");
const plugin = require("tailwindcss/plugin");

module.exports = {
 presets: [preset],
  darkMode: "class",
  
  content: [
    './app/Filament/**/*.php',
    './resources/views/filament/**/*.blade.php',
    './vendor/filament/**/*.blade.php',
    
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.css",
    "./css/**/*.css",
    "./resources/**/*.scss",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./js/**/*.js",
  ],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      lg: "992px",
      md: "768px",
      sm: "480px",
      xl: "1200px",
      xxl: "1400px",
      xxxl: "1800px",
    },
    borderRadius: {
      none: "0",
      sm: "0.375rem",
      md: "0.5rem",
      lg: "0.75rem",
      xl: "1rem",
      '3xl': "1.5rem",
      full: "9999px",
    },
    fontFamily: {
     
      roboto: ['Cairo', 'sans-serif'],
      Montserrat: ["Montserrat","sans-serif"],
      feather: ["feather"],
      boostrap:['bootstrap-icons'],
      archivo: ["Archivo", "sans-serif"]
    },
    fontSize: {
      defaultsize: '0.813rem',
      xs:'0.75rem',
      sm:'0.875rem',
      base:'1rem',
      lg:'1.125rem',
      xl:'1.25rem',
      '2xl':'1.5rem',
      '3xl':'1.875rem',
      '4xl':'2.25rem',
      '5xl':'3rem',
      '6xl':'3.75rem',
      '7xl':'4.5rem',
      '8xl':'6rem',
      '9xl':'8rem',
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        gray: {  
          100: "#f9fafb",
          200: "#f2f4f5",
          300: "#e6eaeb",
          400: "#dbdfe1",
          500: "#949eb7",
          600: "#7987a1",
          700: "#4d5875",
          800: "#383853",
          900: "#323251",
        },
        
        bodybg:"rgb(var(--body-bg))",
        bodybg2:"rgb(var(--dark-bg))",
        primary: "rgb(var(--primary))",
        primaryrgb: "rgb(var(--primary-rgb))",
        secondary: "rgb(var(--secondary))",
        success: "rgb(var(--success))",
        dark: "rgb(var(--dark))",
        info: "rgb(var(--info))",
        warning: "rgb(var(--warning))",
        danger: "rgb(var(--danger))",
        light:"rgb(var(--light))",
        orangemain:"rgb(var(--orange))",
        pinkmain:"rgb(var(--pink))",
        tealmain:"rgb(var(-teal))",
        purplemain:"rgb(var(--purple))",
        defaulttextcolor:"rgb(var(--default-text-color))",
        defaultborder:"rgb(var(--default-border))",
        defaultbackground:"rgb(var(--default-background))",
        
        menuprimecolor:"rgb(var(--menu-prime-color))",
        menubordercolor:"rgb(var(--menu-border-color))",
        headerprimecolor:"rgb(var(--header-prime-color))",
        headerbordercolor:"rgb(var(--header-border-color))",
        bootstrapcardborder:"rgb(var(--bootstrap-card-border))",
        listhoverfocusbg:"rgb(var(--list-hover-focus-bg))",
        textmuted:"rgb(var(--text-muted))",
        inputborder:"rgb(var(--input-border))",
        indigomain:"rgb(var(--indigo))",
        facebook:"rgb(var(--facebook))",
        twitter:"rgb(var(--twitter))",
        github:"rgb(var(--github))",
        google:"rgb(var(--google))",
        youtube:"rgb(var(--youtube))",
      },
      gradientColorStops: {
        primary: 'rgb(var(--primary))',
        secondary: 'rgb(var(--secondary))',
        success: 'rgb(var(--success))',
        warning: 'rgb(var(--warning))',
        pink: 'rgb(var(--pink))',
        teal: 'rgb(var(--teal))',
        danger: 'rgb(var(--danger))',
        info: 'rgb(var(--info))',
        orange: 'rgb(var(--orange))',
        purple: 'rgb(var(--purple))',
        light: 'rgb(var(--light))',
        dark: 'rgb(var(--dark))',
      },
      linearGradientDirections: {
        'to-right': 'to right',
        'to-45': '45deg',
      },
      // linearGradientColors: {
      //   'primary-to-blue': ['primary 0%', '#0086ed 100%'],
      //   'secondary-to-blue': ['secondary 0%', '#6789D8 100%'],
      //   'success-to-blue': ['success 0%', '#00A1C0 100%'],
      //   'warning-to-blue': ['warning 0%', '#7FA53A 100%'],
      //   'pink-to-blue': ['pink 0%', '#FFA795 100%'],
      //   'teal-to-blue': ['teal 0%', '#0695DD 100%'],
      //   'danger-to-blue': ['danger 0%', '#A34A88 100%'],
      //   'info-to-blue': ['info 0%', '#52F0CE 100%'],
      //   'orange-to-blue': ['orange 0%', '#9BA815 100%'],
      //   'purple-to-blue': ['purple 0%', '#FF496D 100%'],
      //   'light-to-blue': ['light 0%', '#D1D6DE 100%'],
      //   'dark-to-blue': ['dark 0%', '#54505D 100%'],
      // },
      boxShadow: {
        defaultshadow:"-8px 12px 18px 0 #dadee8",
        pageshadow: "0 0 1rem rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
        darkpageshadow: "0 0 1rem rgba(255,255,255,0.1)"
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        instagram:
        "linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%, #e6683c 25%, #dc2743 50%, #cc2366 75%, #bc1888 100%)",
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
    },
    animation: {
      projects: "particles 2s linear infinite",
      spin: "spin 1s linear infinite;",
      ping: "ping 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite",
      pulse: "pulse 2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.6, 1) infinite",
      bounce: "bounce 1s infinite",
      bell:"ring 2s ease-in-out infinite",
      loadingtext:"loading 2s infinite",
      wase:"wase 5s linear infinite",
      'spin-slow': 'spin 3s linear infinite',
      'slow-ping':'ping 2s linear infinite',
      'animate-wase': 'wase 4s linear infinite',
      'progress-animate':"2s progressanimate",
    },
    keyframes: {
      particles: {
        "0%": {
          transform: " translateY(0) rotate(0)",
          opacity: 1,
        },
        "100%": {
          transform: "translateY(-90px) rotate(180deg)",
          opacity: " 0",
        },
      },
      spin: {
        from: {
          transform: "rotate(0deg)",
        },
        to: {
          transform: "rotate(360deg)",
        },
      },
      ping: {
        "75%, 100%": {
          transform: "scale(2)",
          opacity: 0,
        },
      },
      pulse: {
        "0%, 100% ": {
          opacity: 1,
        },
        "50%": {
          opacity: 0.5,
        },
      },
      bounce: {
        "0%, 100% ": {
          transform: "translateY(-25%)",
          " animation-timing-function": "cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 1, 1)",
        },
        "50%": {
          transform: "translateY(0)",
          "animation-timing-function": "cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1)",
        },
      },
      ring: {
        "0%": { transform: "rotateZ(0)" },
      "1%": { transform: "rotateZ(30deg)" },
      "3%": { transform: "rotateZ(-28deg)" },
      "5%": { transform: "rotateZ(34deg)" },
      "7%": { transform: "rotateZ(-32deg)" },
      "9%": { transform: "rotateZ(30deg)" },
      "11%": { transform: "rotateZ(-28deg)" },
      "13%": { transform: "rotateZ(26deg)" },
      "15%": { transform: "rotateZ(-24deg)" },
      "17%": { transform: "rotateZ(22deg)" },
      "19%": { transform: "rotateZ(-20deg)" },
      "21%": { transform: "rotateZ(18deg)" },
      "23%": { transform: "rotateZ(-16deg)" },
      "25%": { transform: "rotateZ(14deg)" },
      "27%": { transform: "rotateZ(-12deg)" },
      "29%": { transform: "rotateZ(10deg)" },
      "31%": { transform: "rotateZ(-8deg)" },
      "33%": { transform: "rotateZ(6deg)" },
      "35%": { transform: "rotateZ(-4deg)" },
      "37%": { transform: "rotateZ(2deg)" },
      "39%": { transform: "rotateZ(-1deg)" },
      "41%": { transform: "rotateZ(1deg)" },
      "43%": { transform: "rotateZ(0)" },
      "100%":{ transform: "rotateZ(0)" },
      },
      wase:{
        '0%, 100%': { transform: 'rotate(-3deg)' },
          '50%': { transform: 'rotate(3deg)' },
      },
      progressanimate :{
        "0%" : {
         width : '0',
        }
      },
      loading:{
        "0%": {
          transform: "translateY(-145%)",
          opacity: '0',
        },
        "10%": {
          opacity: '0.5',
        },
        "20%": {
          opacity: '1',
          transform: "translateY(0)",
        },
        "90%": {
          opacity: '0.5',
        },
        "100%": {
          opacity: '0',
          transform: "translateY(145%)",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [
    require("tailwindcss"),
    require("@tailwindcss/forms"),
    // require("tailwind-clip-path"),
    require("preline/plugin"),
    plugin(function ({ addComponents ,addBase}) {
      addComponents({
        ".dirrtl": {
          direction: "ltr",
        },
        ".dir-rtl": {
          direction: "rtl",
        },
        ".dir-ltr": {
          direction: "ltr",
        },
        '.h1': { fontSize: '2.5rem' },
        '.h2': { fontSize: '2rem' },
        '.h3': { fontSize: '1.75rem' },
        '.h4': { fontSize: '1.5rem' },
        '.h5': { fontSize: '1.25rem' },
        '.h6': { fontSize: '1rem' },
      });
      addBase({
        'h1': { fontSize: '2.5rem' },
        'h2': { fontSize: '2rem' },
        'h3': { fontSize: '1.75rem' },
        'h4': { fontSize: '1.5rem' },
        'h5': { fontSize: '1.25rem' },
        'h6': { fontSize: '1rem' },
      })
    }),
  ],
};

